# I found ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I try to run python on CMD.
I import tensorflow.contrib in my python file.

```
import tensorflow.contrib.tensorrt as trt
```

when running on anaconda with this command.

```
python run_webcam.py --camera yoga.mp4
```

it show error:

```
  File "run_webcam.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tf_pose.estimator import TfPoseEstimator
  File "D:\work\pose estimation\tf-pose-estimation\tf_pose\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from tf_pose.runner import infer, Estimator, get_estimator
  File "D:\work\pose estimation\tf-pose-estimation\tf_pose\runner.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tf_pose import eval
  File "D:\work\pose estimation\tf-pose-estimation\tf_pose\eval.py", line 13, in <module>
    from tf_pose.estimator import TfPoseEstimator
  File "D:\work\pose estimation\tf-pose-estimation\tf_pose\estimator.py", line 14, in <module>
    import tensorflow.contrib.tensorrt as trt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'
```

I installed

```
pip install tensorflow
```

and change the version of tensorflow (Try to uninstall and install many version )

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install tensorflow==...
```

but show the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the following

`import tensorflow.contrib.tensorrt as trt` (used in ≤ TensorFlow 1.13.1 )

with

`from tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt import trt`(TensorFlow ≥ 1.14.1)

Credit to [GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorrt/issues/84#issuecomment-502771936)

Comment: my TensorFlow version is tensorflow 2.2.0rc2 and I import like that .I still error.
When I try ``` from tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt import trt ``` and change version. it error same too.

@incarnadine

Comment: this error when use from tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt import trt in version 1.15.0

" ImportError: cannot import name 'trt_convert' from 'tensorflow.python.compile
r.tensorrt  "